# Youtube Analytics API v3 - retrieving relative audience retention

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics, youtube-analytics-api

I'm trying to retrieve information from Youtube Analytics API v3.

The API allows us to retrieve two metrics about audience retention: audienceWatchRatio and relativeRetentionPerformance.

The audienceWatchRatio datas perfectly match the absolute audience retention chart that is displayed on the Youtube Analytics website.

Unfortunately, the relativeRetentionPerformance datas don't match at all the relative audience retention chart that is displayed on the Youtube Analytics website. You will find a comparison between both charts on the image below.

Does anyone knows how to retrieve the relative audience retention datas that are displayed on the Youtube Analytics website?

Thank you a lot for reading and maybe for answering!

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? Have you scoured the [Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/) for possible solution?

Comment: Sure, I've spent hours on it. The bulk reports provide only one metric about audience retention ([audience_retention_percentage](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reports/metrics#Audience_Retention_Metrics)) and target queries only two ([audienceWatchRatio and relativeRetentionPerformance](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#audience-retention-reports) ). Unfortunately, none of those match the relative audience retention chart that is displayed on Youtube Analytics website.

Comment: @Jose-XavierMorin just wondering if you had solved this ? I'm looking for the same information.